# Find lists containing ALL values in a set?

Tags: sparql, rdf

How can I find lists that contain each of a set of items in SPARQL? Let's say I have this data:

```
<http://foo.org/test> <http://foo.org/name> ( "new" "fangled" "thing" )  . 
<http://foo.org/test2> <http://foo.org/name> ( "new" "york" "city" )  .
```

How can I find the items whose lists contain both "new" and "york"?
The following SPARQL doesn't work, since **filter** works on each binding of **?t**, not the set of all of them.

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT ?s ?p WHERE {       
    ?s <http://foo.org/name>/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?t 
    FILTER( ?t = "new" && ?t = "york")   
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Finding lists with multiple required values

If you're looking for lists that contain *all* of a number of values, you'll need to use a more complicated query.  This query finds all the **?s** values that have a **?list** value, and then filters out those where there is *not* a word that is *not* in the list.  The list of words is specified using a **values** block.

```sql
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?s {
  ?s <http://foo.org/name> ?list .
  filter not exists {                   #-- It's not the case
     values ?word { "new" "york" }      #-- that any of the words
     filter not exists {                #-- are not
       ?list rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?word  #-- in the list.
     }
  }
}
```

```
--------------------------
| s                      |
==========================
| <http://foo.org/test2> |
--------------------------
```

### Find alternative strings in a list

On the other hand, if you're just trying to search for one of a number of options, you're using the right property path, but you've got the wrong filter expression.  You want strings equals to "new" **or** "york".  No string is equal to both "new" **and** "york".  You just need to do **filter(?t = "new" || ?t = "york")** or better yet use [**in**](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-in): **filter(?t in ("new", "york"))**.   Here's a full example with results:

```sql
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?s ?t {
  ?s <http://foo.org/name>/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?t .
  filter(?t in ("new","york"))
}
```

```
-----------------------------------
| s                      | t      |
===================================
| <http://foo.org/test2> | "new"  |
| <http://foo.org/test2> | "york" |
| <http://foo.org/test>  | "new"  |
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Wow, I've wrestled with this issue for days. You rock Josh ! I'd buy you a beer if I could

Comment: @AriesOnTheCusp This might even be a duplicate, but it's not an easy one to search for.  It's a little bit strange in that you're essentially having to search for a double negation of some condition, but can't search for the condition directly.

Comment: @AriesOnTheCusp Here's [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22407714/1281433) that's got some of the same patterns (see the last SPARQL query in the answer), used for examining some OWL expressions.

Comment: Correct, it was very difficult to search for. I'm still reading through the Sparql 1.1 W3 documents, but I actually did see that other SO post you referenced. They used alot of  owl:intersectionOf  and etc and I incorrectly assumed the entire post wouldnt apply to my question. I kept thinking there had to be an easier way. Like why didnt they just add an intersection or contains method/keyword. Thanks again